# raspberry pi bootup error

Tags: boot-issues

i modified swap file size, boot options, and memory split in my raspberry pi to install dlib faster
here are the modifications

1. Increased the swap file size to 1024.
2. Switched the boot option to autologin (B2).
3. Updated the GPU/RAM split to 16MB (intially 64MB.

my problem is:
i tried connecting a pi screen. the pi gets stuck at: 
i2c /dev entries driver

Question 1 : Pls how can i at least access the terminal and undo the modifications i did

Question 2: If i cant, how can solve the 'i2c /dev entries driver' problem

Question 3: can i access the recovery mode without my sd card being affected?

thanks alot.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is too broad. Such questions are flagged and may be closed. This site isn't made for brainstorming and discuss general issues. It is made to do one specific question that can be answered detailed. You may visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that your Raspberry Pi has no real BIOS and just a `/boot/config.txt` file with all the options. Put your micro SD card into a SD card reader in your PC and change those options back.
For the screen you might need to open an interface thru `sudo raspi-config`.

Comment: i even formatted the sd card. installed a new OS, but the pi is not booting. its even worse. it shows only the white screen. however, other sd card worked when i tested. my initial sd card is not corrupt but i cant understand why the pi does not recognise the sd card anymore

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullahi, how do you know the original SD card is not corrupted? If your RPi does work with other SD cards, I would think the first card is to blame. There's this [method to determine if your SD card is defective or fake](https://superuser.com/questions/631633/how-to-tell-if-you-have-a-fake-sd-card). If you really think your SD card is not corrupter, that test.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by using a new sd card to do fresh raspbian install. i had no other way working out. furthermore, the best headless raspberry pi install (mac) i found online is at: https://youtu.be/-v88m-HYeys. easy pizzy